# How do i find the license key for this program?

Tags: c, linux, reverse-engineering, ltrace

I'm trying to solve this exercise for university. We have to "crack" a program, which is missing a license file that is required to start the program. We are only working with a Linux shell.

So what I've already done is creating this missing license file. It is an .ini that includes a license-holder and a license key. The only thing i'm looking for now is the correct license key. The task says we should use "strace" and "ltrace" to solve this problem.
This is what i get as an output:

```
fopen("license.ini", "r")                                   =0x55c088307380

fgets("LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 4096, 0x55c088307380)  = 0x7ffe72450860

strncmp("LicenseKey=", "LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 11)   = 3

strncmp("LicenseHolder=", "LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 14)    = 0

sscanf(0x7ffe72450860, 0x55c08753c16b, 0x7ffe72450800, 0xffffc000)  = 1

fgets("LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 4096, 0x55c088307380) = 0x7ffe72450860

strncmp("LicenseKey=", "LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 11)           = 0

sscanf(0x7ffe72450860, 0x55c08753c121, 0x7ffe72450840, 0xfffff800)  = 1

fgets("LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 4096, 0x55c088307380)          = 0

memfrob(0x7ffe72450840, 8, 0, 0xfbad2498)                   = 0x7ffe72450840

strncmp("KEOAFSIL", "aoeklycf", 8)                          = -22

fwrite("ERROR: License key is invalid.\n", 1, 31, 0x7faeabe60680
ERROR: License key is invalid.
)                                   = 31

+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

So I guess the answer lies somewhere within the memfrob and strncmp function at the end. But i don't know what's the next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the library trace call by call. The important part is in step 5.

#### Analysis

1. **Open the file**

   ```
   fopen("license.ini", "r")                                   =0x55c088307380
   ```

   Opens the license file.
2. **Parse the license holder**

   ```
   fgets("LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 4096, 0x55c088307380)  = 0x7ffe72450860
   ```

   Reads a line from the file: `LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex…`.

   ```
   strncmp("LicenseKey=", "LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 11)   = 3
   ```

   Does the line start with `LicenseKey=`? The return value of `3` means no, it does not.

   ```
   strncmp("LicenseHolder=", "LicenseHolder=annabell.krause@ex"..., 14)    = 0
   ```

   Does the line start with `LicenseHolder=`? Yes, it does.

   ```
   sscanf(0x7ffe72450860, 0x55c08753c16b, 0x7ffe72450800, 0xffffc000)  = 1
   ```

   Unfortunately, ltrace has not dereferenced any of the addresses to show us the contents. We know that 0x7ffe72450860 is the current line, so it's presumably pulling out the e-mail address from the current line.
3. **Parse the license key**

   ```
   fgets("LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 4096, 0x55c088307380) = 0x7ffe72450860
   ```

   It reads another line: `LicenseKey=aoeklycf`.

   ```
   strncmp("LicenseKey=", "LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 11)           = 0
   ```

   Does the line start with `LicenseKey=`? Yes, it does.

   ```
   sscanf(0x7ffe72450860, 0x55c08753c121, 0x7ffe72450840, 0xfffff800)  = 1
   ```

   It's parsing the current line. Presumably, it's extracting the license key you entered, `aoeklycf`, and saving it in a variable for later comparison against the expected license key. Something like `sscanf(line, "LicenseKey=%s", licenseKey);`.
4. **End-of-file**

   ```
   fgets("LicenseKey=aoeklycf", 4096, 0x55c088307380)          = 0
   ```

   It tries to read another line and hits EOF. Ignore the first argument, it's just showing what was left in the buffer from the last call.
5. **License key comparison**

   ```
   memfrob(0x7ffe72450840, 8, 0, 0xfbad2498)                   = 0x7ffe72450840
   ```

   "Encrypts" 8 bytes of some memory area by XORing each byte with 42. This can be reversed by running `memfrob()` again. I put "encrypts" in air quotes because this can barely be called encryption. It's just a little bit of obfuscation.

   Notice that 0x7ffe72450840 is the address from the `sscanf()` above. It's frobbing the variable I called `licenseKey` above, the `LicenseKey=` string it extracted from the input file.

   ```
   strncmp("KEOAFSIL", "aoeklycf", 8)                          = -22
   ```

   This is the money line. It compares actual and expected values and fails.
6. **Error message**

   ```
   fwrite("ERROR: License key is invalid.\n", 1, 31, 0x7faeabe60680)                                   = 31
   ```

   An error is printed.

#### Synthesis

But the author doesn't want you to be able to run a simple string search like `strings ./program` to pull the license key out of the executable. To prevent that you have to enter the *frobbed* version of the license key in `license.ini`, not the raw string `strings` finds.

The code might look something like:

```
char *expected = "aoeklycf";
char actual[BUFSIZE];

sscanf(line, "LicenseKey=%s", actual);
memfrob(actual);
if (strncmp(actual, expected, strlen(expected)) != 0) {
    error("ERROR: License key is invalid.\n");
}
```

Did you extract `aoeklycf` from the program? If so, you missed the `memfrob()` step. `license.ini` needs to list the "encrypted" version of the license key: `KEOAFSIL`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But could you explain to me how this works in detail? Because when i enter a license key different to "aoeklycf", the first output "KEOAFSIL" changes too. Is "aoeklycf" the encrypted form of "KEOAFSIL" due to the memfrob function?

Comment: Ah yes i extracted `aoeklycf` from the programm. Ok, now i understand. Thanks again for the explanation.